# VS 2022 C# Server hot reload with docker

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio, kestrel-http-server

I work on several C# backends that serve up through kestrel and the whole thing is developed and deployed in dockers.  Everything works fine, but I would love to get hot reload working for development.

There seems to be 2 different issues

1. Although all projects come from a common source, some show the hot reload button, others are disabled
2. Those where it is enabled, it doesn't work.  I'm afraid I can't recall the exact error and the projects I have to hand aren't offering it, but basically it's along the lines of not possible

Is hot reload of changes in this scenario possible?

Answer (score 4):

At this time, hot reload is not supported in the Container tooling for Visual Studio.  It is something that is being investigated and is being tracked at https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/322

Comment: thanks for your reply, I'll keep an eye on the issue

Comment: Hot Reload is now supported in Visual Studio 2022 17.8 or later